# Finding a natural transformation between the double dual functor and the trivial one

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, proof-writing

My question is about to find a natural transformation from $t$ to the trivial functor, and $t$ goes from the following:

$$\mathbb{V} \to \mathbb{V^{*}} \to \mathbb{V}$$

then $t$ has to go from $\mathbb{V} \to \mathbb{V}$

where $\mathbb{V}$ is the category of vector spaces and $\mathbb{V^{*}}$ is that of the dual spaces.

I am really sorry if I am missing something but the thing is that I do not know how to begin or work with this, that is why I appreciate a very explicit answer with all the details, thanks in advance for your help, I really appreciate it :).

I have found the following information, but I don't know if it helps, here http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Category_Theory/Natural_transformations where it says motivating example :)

Here is the exact exercise :)

Show that exists a natural transformation from $t$ to the trivial functor, t is the one above

Comment: Could you start by reproducing the problem you're trying to solve in its entirety? There doesn't seem to be a complete definition of $t$ here.

Comment: well the thing is that this would help us to say that the dual of the dual is almost the same space, that is why $t$ goes from v to v, I am sorry for the missunderstanding :)

Comment: I have found the following information, but I don't know if it helps, here http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Category_Theory/Natural_transformations where it says motivating example :)

Comment: x @user: You need to supply an actual definition of $t$, not just tell us which categories it goes between. (Except for trivial answers such as between any two functors from **Vec** to **Vec**, there's a natural transformation, by letting every $\eta_X$ be the zero map).

Comment: well is the only thing I have in my notes :( before that I have a functor define by the teacher from the vector spaces to the dual spaces

Comment: x @user: The least you could do is show the actual statement of the problem (that is, quote it verbatim) instead of trying to paraphrase it.

Comment: When the problem you quote says "$t$ is the one above", it means that somewhere above the single line you quote is a definition of $t$. _That definition is part of the problem statement you need to quote_.

Comment: well I know what are you talking about but the one above I put that because I could no post the image :( and well I hope that I could do something else but i can't :( how can I post the picture :(

Comment: Well, then my best advice would be to say "there is a natural transformation from $t$ to $Id$, namely the one where $\eta_X$ is the zero map $t(X)\to X$ for every vector space $X$". That can't fail to work, but is not very interesting either.

Comment: thanks a lot for it I would try to do something more let me see :)

Comment: Note that if $t$ is the functor that takes every $X$ to its double dual and lifts maps in the obvious way, then there is an interesting natural transformation from $Id$ to $t$. But in the other direction I can't come up with anything interesting.

Comment: ok, and can you describe the interesting case more explicit please :)

Answer (score 3):

Let's assume your $t$ is the double dual functor $ V\mapsto V^{**}, f\mapsto f^{**}$. Then for every $V$ there's a map $\alpha_V:V\to V^{**}$ sending $v\mapsto (\xi\mapsto \xi(v))$. I claim this extends to a natural transformation $1_{\mathbb{V}}\to t$: if $f:V\to W$ then we need $\alpha_W\circ f=f^{**}\circ \alpha_V$. We have $\alpha_W\circ f(v)=(\zeta\mapsto \zeta(f(v)))$ and $f^{**}\circ\alpha_V(v)=f^{**}(\xi\mapsto \xi(v))=(\zeta\mapsto \zeta(f(v))$, as desired.

Here it's worth spelling out $f^{**}$. $f^*:W^*\to V^*$ is given by $f^*(\zeta)(v)=\zeta(f(v))$. So $f^{**}:V^{**}\to W^{**}$ is given by $f^{**}(t)(\zeta)=t(f^*\zeta)$. In our example $t$ is the element $\xi\mapsto \xi(v)$ of $V^{**}$, and $f^{**}t(\zeta)=t(f^*\zeta)=t(v\mapsto \zeta(f(v)))=\zeta(f(v))$, as I claimed above. All of this is probably horribly messy to try to read, and I recommend that you try to write it out again yourself.

Anyway, we now have a natural transformation from the identity on finite-dimensional vector spaces to $t$. This goes in the opposite direction from what you wanted, but in the finite dimensional case $\alpha$ is a natural isomorphism, so take its inverse.

Comment: thanks a lot @Kevin Carlson, and with this all is covered right?, well assuming that t is the double dual functor :)

Comment: Yes, I've mentioned everything that needs to be mentioned (the inverse of a natural isomorphism is automatically natural, which you should write down once if you never have.) And I'm certain $t$ is the double dual-this is the most, er, natural example of a natural transformation at the undergraduate level.

Comment: well I didn't understand the las part but thanks a lot, theres no more math right?